# Is it possible to trigger a Gitlab CICD pipeline with an OAuth2.0 token rather than personal access token?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to trigger a pipeline with only a valid Oauth2 Gitlab token. I would assume the API request would look like this:

```
curl --request POST "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/pipeline?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN"
```

Per the Gitlab docs, it's possible to use an OAuth token with Gitlab. We've successfully generated an OAuth2 token with our Gitlab by verifying a generated token using the token info endpoint.

Additionally, Gitlab documentation suggests its entirely possible to use the OAuth2 token to authenticate to API resources:

> OAuth 2.0 tokens You can use an OAuth 2.0 token to authenticate with
> the API by passing it in either the access_token parameter or the
> Authorization header.
>
> Example of using the OAuth 2.0 token in a parameter:
>
> `curl "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects?access_token=OAUTH-TOKEN"`
>
> Example of using the OAuth 2.0 token in a header:
>
> `curl --header "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH-TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"`

^ - [Source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#authentication)

> OAuth 2.0 identity provider API provides an API to allow third-party services to access GitLabresources on a user’s behalf with the OAuth 2.0 protocol.
>
> To configure GitLab for this, see Configure GitLab as an OAuth 2.0
> authentication identity provider.
>
> This functionality is based on the doorkeeper Ruby gem.

^ - [Source](https://html)

Currently, I've only managed the following in my third party application in order to generate a pipeline run:

```
curl --request POST \
  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $YOUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $YOUR_OAUTH_BEARER_TOKEN" \
  --url "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/$PROJECT_ID/trigger/pipeline" \
  --form "token=$TRIGGER_TOKEN"
```

- Pre-generate a group token with API access,
- Pre-generate a trigger token within a project within the Group of the above group token,
- Send an API request with the group token, trigger token, and Oauth2.0 token to successfully trigger a pipeline.

**Problems / Limitations with the current solution**

- Uses a group token which must be stored in the application.
- Depends on statically defined tokens generated in advance rather than on-the-fly.
- The resulting pipeline is "triggered" by whomever generated the trigger token in the project.

Answer (score 0):

We have a dev and a prod gitlab. Generally it helps when you generate your OAuth token against the same gitlab instance you're trying to trigger the pipeline against. Confirming you can trigger a pipeline with just an OAuth token, like so:

```
curl -X POST "https://${GITLAB_URL}/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/pipeline?ref=${BRANCH_NAME}&access_token=${TOKEN}"
```